# Any way to preview .aspx file that's got JSON linked

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, online

We're trying to see if we can use SP as a web hosting platform. Aspx files can be previewed that only have html/css/JS linked.

But when it comes to JSON, the .aspx file doesn't load...

Now this might be a SP limitation, unless someone can point me in the right direction/see if there's a way?

Comment: Are you attempting to create a public website on SharePoint Online?

Comment: I guess so... Imagine the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting public websites on SharePoint Online is not possible:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/public-websites-be-discontinued